# Creating MS Word file with texreg

Tags: regression, texreg

I am trying to generate an MS Word document that contains a table with my regression results. I am producing a simple linear model (i.e. lm function) and using the code below to generate the table and file. A file is created but each line of the table is on its own separate page. Any ideas why this might be happening? The code below is nearly identical to that offered in the texreg package documentation with the exception that I am trying to export the results from one rather than two models. I get the same strange result on my MAC and PC. If I change the output file to "texreg.html", the table appears fine opened in a browser.

```
htmlreg(model1, file = "texreg.doc", 
inline.css = FALSE, doctype = TRUE, html.tag = TRUE, 
head.tag = TRUE, body.tag = TRUE)
unlink("texreg.doc")
```

Comment: What Word version are you using? On my test computer (Windows 7, MS Office Professional Plus 2010, version 14.0.6023.1000, 32 bit), this works well. I am using the example in the ``lm`` help file. The fact that the HTML file displays correctly means that the output file per se is readable, so it must be related to your Word version or settings. Have you tried to rename to ``.xls`` and open it in Excel? What ``texreg`` version are you using? 1.31.4?

Comment: I am using Word for Mac, version 2011. If it works for you then it likely is related to my Mac version of World although I wouldn't know what settings to change in Word to fix the problem

Comment: 1) Try it with the first example in the ``lm`` help file and tell me if it produces the same problem.
2) Rename the output to ``.xls`` and check whether Excel can open it without any problem.
3) Try it in OpenOffice and let me know if it works.
4) There is a function in Word that lets you import HTML content. Normally, this shouldn't be necessary, but you might want to try it and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (also using Word for Mac, version 2011). Strange enough, I could solve it by closing Microsoft Word (i.e. closing any open Word document, as well as not having Word itself running) before running the above commands in R.